# Reading TEXT column into a TEXT variable in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to read an XML file through a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
CREATE table #temp
(
    temp TEXT
)

DECLARE @sql_bulk NVARCHAR(500), @path  NVARCHAR(500)

SET @sql_bulk = 'BULK INSERT #temp FROM '''+ @path+''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''|\n'' )'

EXEC (@sql_bulk)

DECLARE @hDoc AS INT,@xml_text AS VARCHAR(8000)

select @xml_text = temp FROM #temp

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml_text
```

This works well as long as my XML is small. To handle large XMLs, I intend to define the variable `@xml_text` as `TEXT` (as a parameter to the stored procedure).

But the challenge now I'm facing is how to assign the column value to the `TEXT` variable? Apparently I can't use `SET` or `SELECT` to assign value to a `TEXT` variable. I also tried `READTEXT` to no avail.